# Симуляция пользователя на сайте

Tags: php, curl

Забираю данные с сайта через curl, но сайт в 8 из 10 запросов отдает мне контент для ботов. Как при использовании php curl-а прикинуться простым пользователем? Спасибо

Comment: Берете движок браузера. Обвешиваете его скриптами поведения. Получаете результат.

Comment: паузы между запросами делать не пробовали?

Comment: proxy используете? заголовки User-Agent меняете?

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer прокси нет, юзер агент меняю.

Comment: @J.Doe купите проксей и будет вам счастье. Возможно ))

Comment: @Visman, мы пробовали так парсить на автоите ИЕхой. Это боль.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer я думаю тут речь скорее о касперджс. Это тоже боль, пробовал до курла, надеялся что смогу без него обойтись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

никак. Используй всякие headless браузеры, курл не поддерживает имитацию пользователя, он лишь отправляет запрос и получает ответ.

Если хоть немного разбираешься в js и работал с node.js, то есть casperjs/phantomjs, все довольно просто.